# Filtering by attribute in d3 map

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to filter the points displayed on a map based on attribute, with checkboxes.  I have:

```
<div class="filter_options">
    <input class="filter_button" id="HOMICIDE" type="checkbox">a</input><br>
    <input class="filter_button" id="ROBBERY" type="checkbox">b</input><br>
    <input class="filter_button" id="ASSAULT" type="checkbox">c</input><br>
```

So, i assign a value to each checkbox:

```
document.getElementById("HOMICIDE").value = "HOMICIDE"
document.getElementById("ASSAULT").value = "ASSAULT"
```

Then, I want to match the value of checkbox to value of crime type ('Primary_Type) in my data:

```
d3.selectAll(".filter_button").on("change", function() {
  d3.selectAll('.incident').remove();
  var type = this.value, 

  // I *think* "inline" is the default.
  display = this.checked ? "inline" : "none";
console.log(type)
  svg.selectAll(".incident")
    .filter(function(d) { return d.properties.Primary_Type === type; })
    .attr("display", display)
    .style("opacity", 1)
    

});
```

However, nothing is appearing on map, so filter is not working correctly.

Comment: you first delete all the `.incident` items and then modify attributes of these. Just set `opacity` to 0 or ` based on the property equality. You have check boxes so you have to take into account the combinations of checks in the `opacity` check

Comment: thanks - but i'm guessing something is up w/ my equality statement since its not working - any thoughts why this is?  I still need the equality statement to work properly even if I use the opacity approach.